# Custom List Menu Item not appearing

Tags: list, custom, item

I've been trying to create a custom list menu item on my SharePoint list. After consulting tutorials, I've created the feature settings and attached an element.xml file as shown below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <CustomAction
       Id="DoSomethingFancy"
       RegistrationType="List"
       RegistrationId="107"
       Location="EditControlBlock"
       Sequence="199"
       Title="DoSomethingCool"
       Description="Open this item in a new window"
       ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/funny.gif">
       <UrlAction Url="javascript:window.open(‘DispForm.aspx?ID={ItemId}');" />
     </CustomAction>
   </Elements>
```

However, when I deploy my solution, the menu item does not appear. The same problem exists with the Custom Action Menu Item. I can add this item using the SharePoint Designer but I do not want to have to do this for each list item as they are generated dynamically by the user.

Can anyone suggest how I may resolve this?